# libtool: Cannot find the library... Why?

Tags: c, libtool, gtk2, anjuta

Though I rarely create static libraries, after updating Slackware, I get the following error:

`libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la' or unhandled argument '/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la'`

The project does not create libraries. Also Slackware removes the .la files.

Q: How can I find out which part of the program is requiring `libfontconfig.la`? And why?

Q: Should `libtool` be called at all?

**Answers to your suggestions**

*From the make output, find which directory has the problem.*

It's simply the src/ directory in the project root:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -g -g -O2 -Wl,--export-dynamic  -o farma1 callbacks.o main.o extracts.o import.o my_sql.o paradox.o global.o article.o clients.o orders.o stats.o support.o interface.o sales.o fprint.o access.o mutual.o dialogs.o -lgnomeui-2 -lSM -lICE -lbonoboui-2 -lgnome-2 -lpopt -lbonobo-2 -lbonobo-activation -lORBit-2 -lgnomecanvas-2 -lart_lgpl_2 -lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lconfmgr3 -L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb 
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la' or unhandled argument '/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:476: farma1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/projects/clients/farma/software/farma1a/src'
```

*Examine the Makefile in that directory, and find which variable is assigned the string libfontconfig.la. It might be something like BLAH_LIBS = ${libdir}/libfontconfig.la*

`libfontconfig.la` is never mentioned in that Makefile. It *is* included in `FARMA1_LIBS =`, I believe correctly, as `-lfontconfig`.

I also scanned /usr/lib64/pkgconfig for any file mentioning `fontconfig`. A few did mention it, but none mentioned a `.la` file.

To be sure, I also checked `/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig`. I also scanned the entire project directory, recurively, and to no avail.

*** EDITED ***

While `src/Makefile` didn't require itself, it does seem to do so indirectly. I captured the `libtool` command's output, using:
`../libtool --debug --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -g -g -O2 -Wl,--export-dynamic  -o farma1 callbacks.o main.o extracts.o import.o my_sql.o paradox.o global.o article.o clients.o orders.o stats.o support.o interface.o sales.o fprint.o access.o mutual.o ..... -lconfmgr3 -L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb > log 2>&1`
and found, near the end, where the error occured:

```
...
case $1 in
+ . /usr/lib64//libgnomecanvas-2.la
++ dlname=libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
++ library_names='libgnomecanvas-2.so.0.3000.3 libgnomecanvas-2.so.0 libgnomecanvas-2.so'
++ old_library=libgnomecanvas-2.a
++ inherited_linker_flags=' -pthread'
++ dependency_libs=' -lgailutil -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lart_lgpl_2 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la -lexpat -lfreetype -lm'
++ weak_library_names=
++ current=3000
++
...
```

in the line starting with `dependency_libs`

Comment: libtool is used at build-time while ld is at run-time.

Comment: You're right, of course. I shouldn't ask questions at 3 AM. I meant the linker stage of GCC.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the smoking gun is `unhandled argument '/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la'` - this means that somewhere in your Makefiles, the string `/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.la` appears. It appears that your project depends directly or indirectly on the fontconfig library. The steps I'd use to trace this are:

1. From the make output, find which directory has the problem.
2. Examine the `Makefile` in that directory, and find which variable is assigned the string libfontconfig.la. It might be something like `BLAH_LIBS = ${libdir}/libfontconfig.la`
3. That variable name, BLAH_LIBS is probably generated by pkgconfig, due to a
   configure.ac statement like `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([BLAH], [blah])` which says 'look for the package "blah", and from its blah.pc file, construct the `BLAH_LIBS` and `BLAH_CFLAGS` variables by using the prefix BLAH and the suffix _LIBS and _CFLAGS, and substitute them in Makefiles wherever `@BLAH_LIBS@` and `@BLAH_CFLAGS@` appear'
4. The file blah.pc, distributed by the blah package likely contains the hardcoded "libfontconfig.la" reference, on the `Libs:` line.

The bug is in the package `blah`, specifically the file `/lib/pkgconfig/blah.pc` or similar. It should be -lfontconfig rather than "libfontconfig.la"

For your second question, I agree that if your program does not create libraries, shared or static, it does not need to use libtools at all.

Comment: I am also facing this error in buildroot, in lldpd package, when I try to run make in the "output/product-name/build/lldpd/" directory, I get the error: libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/home/ngadre/Documents/release6.6.1/caos/output/product-name/target/usr/lib/libjansson.la'

Comment: The makefile has the proper string: LIBS = -lz -ljansson

Comment: If libtool complains about something on its command line, then find out where that command line comes from. If "caos" is referring to [this program](https://hal.science/hal-00416911v1/file/356-4-1263.pdf), then it does require X, hence the fontconfig package. If lldpd depends on something in the caos directory, then you might have a PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable which is pointing towards the caos program. I'd suggest tracing the problem one step at the time, methodically. First, find the command line that references `libfontconfig.la` , and trace from there.

Comment: In many projects you can use `make V=1` to display the commands as they're being executed.

Comment: @JaredoMills, First my apologies for the huge delay - life caught up and I had to leave that project by force. Thanks for the extensive explanation. That's what I suspected the mechanism to be, so most the checks I had already done. I also did a check (with `ldd`) if any of the other libraries included called for the .la lib. I edited the question with more info.